# Storing attributes for a user in multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a game and I want to store the number of times a player has won on a certain map type. I want to track the wins for all time, and monthly, so I can offer two leaderboard views for them. My user stats object looks something like this:

```
class UserStats {
    user_id;
    num_wins_map_1;
    num_wins_map_2;
    num_wins_map_n;
    num_wins_for_map_1_this_month;
    num_wins_for_map_2_this_month;
    num_wins_for_map_n_this_month;
    ...
}
```

translating that into my mysql instance, I was thinking of creating two tables:

```
stats_all_time
fk_user_id | num_wins_for_map_1 | num_wins_for_map_2 | num_wins_for_map_n

stats_monthly
fk_user_id | num_wins_for_map_1 | num_wins_for_map_2 | num_wins_for_map_n
```

but with that I'll be adding num_users rows to each of those tables. In other words, when a new user joins, I'll be adding a new row to not just my existing "users" table, but also to the "stats_all_time" and "stats_monthly" tables.

I could add all these fields directly to the existing "users" table, but that won't scale well as I'll have a lot of maps and other stats that need to be indexed, I may hit the InnoDb column limit at some point.

Any recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally nicer to have map as it's own table and a table joining the information:

I.e.

```
Table Map
   id
   name
```

Stats is then just a table linking maps and users with a column for the wins.

Nicer however would be to have stats record the wins:

```
Table wins
    id
    map_id
    user_id
    date
```

This means that you don't have to add new columns any time a new map is added and you can generate whatever stats you want - you're not limited to the all time and monthly tables:

```
-- Quick example queries - may be wrong
-- All time stats
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wins WHERE user_id = X;

-- Monthly
SELECT MONTH(date),YEAR(date),COUNT(*) FROM wins WHERE user_id = X GROUP BY MONTH(date),YEAR(date);

-- Wins scoreboard in the last week
SELECT COUNT(*),user_id FROM wins WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Comment: That all makes sense, I guess the downside is that this could potentially generate a lot of rows.